# An empty array is returned when trying to fetch data from mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/chatterApp', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', () => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
});

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number
});

const userModel = mongoose.model("testUsers", userSchema);

app.get("/getUsers", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const testUsers = await userModel.find({});
        res.json(testUsers);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
    }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('server is running');
});
```

New to MongoDb dont know what went wrong
Need to fetch data from DB
The server is running and connected to DB
There is also data in db
Need help

Comment: May it be that no data is present in the database?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be careful with the first augment of the `mongoose.model()` method as it accepts the *singular* name of the collection.

> The first argument is the singular name of the collection your model is for. Mongoose automatically looks for the plural, lowercased version of your model name. Thus, for the example above, the model Tank is for the tanks collection in the database.

To illustrate, you have:

```
const userModel = mongoose.model("testUsers", userSchema);
```

This means mongoose will look for a collection named `testuserss`. I presume your collection name doesn't have a double s.

However, I have tested this using Mongoose v7.1.1 and v7.4.3 and it seems to be very forgiving, despite what their docs say. When the model name ends in an 's' it would appear that mongoose **does not** add another 's' which is very nice fallback.

Nevertheless, if you don't want mongoose to infer your collection name from the first argument you can pass the actual collection name as the [optional third parameter](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#Mongoose.prototype.model()) like so:

```
const userModel = mongoose.model("testUsers", userSchema, 'coolcollection');
```

Comment: You're welcome. I found that Mongoose will plularise the model name based on some rules [here](https://github.com/vkarpov15/mongoose-legacy-pluralize/blob/master/index.js).